# How to un-silent exec in vim only if there is an error?

Tags: autocmd, microsoft-windows

I have a few hotkeys mapped in my .vimrc (see below) for compiling and running autohotkey scripts but I can either be annoyed by the quest for the <kbd>any</kbd> key or I can run them `silent` and be unaware if there are errors.

```
autocmd filetype autohotkey nnoremap <S-F5> :w <bar> silent exec '!"C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\Compiler\Ahk2Exe.exe" /in '.shellescape('%')<CR>
autocmd filetype autohotkey nnoremap <C-F5> :w <bar> silent exec '!"C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\Compiler\Ahk2Exe.exe" /in '.shellescape('%').' && start .\'.shellescape('%:r')<CR>
autocmd filetype autohotkey nnoremap <S-F6> :silent exec '!Taskkill /IM '.shellescape('%:r').'.exe /F'<CR>
autocmd filetype autohotkey nnoremap <C-S-F5> :silent exec '!Taskkill /IM '.shellescape('%:r').'.exe /F' <bar> silent exec '!"C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\Compiler\Ahk2Exe.exe" /in '.shellescape('%').' && start .\'.shellescape('%:r')<CR>
```

**How do I have these `exec` commands keep the cmd window open *only* if there is an error?**

(e.g. if I run the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and the compiled version is already running, the compile will fail because it can't write to the .exe. (Yes, I know in that particular case there's an evil modal popup but in other cases, there's not good feedback of failure.))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the AutoHotkey compiler properly reports its success via the *exit status* (I haven't checked), you can keep the `:silent` and just delay the closing of the command prompt by executing the `pause` command (which waits for a keypress) in case compilation fails:

```
:silent exec '!"C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\Compiler\Ahk2Exe.exe" /in '.shellescape('%') . ' || pause'<CR>
```

and here's a [reference for the command failed redirect](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) (double pipe `||`)

#### Alternatives

You could invoke the external command via `:let output = system(...)`, and then conditionally `:echo` or discard the output based on `v:shell_error` (or even by inspecting the output by matching "interesting" strings, if you want to ignore some compiler errors or as a solution if the exit status always is `0`).

Actually, you then should go the whole round and write a proper *compiler plugin* ([`:help :compiler`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acompiler), [`:help write-compiler-plugin`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#write-compiler-plugin)). With this, you can trigger via `:make`, and can use the *quickfix list* to view and navigate to compiler errors (assuming the error output is properly structured and parsable).

#### Additional critique

> ```
> nnoremap <S-F5> ...
> ```

As these mappings only apply to AutoHotkey buffers, you should limit the scope of those mappings via `:nnoremap <buffer> ...`

---

I would recommend putting any settings, mappings, and filetype-specific autocmds into `~/.vim/ftplugin/{filetype}_whatever.vim` (or `{filetype}/whatever.vim`; cp. `:help ftplugin-name`) instead of defining lots of `:autocmd FileType {filetype}`; it's cleaner and scales better; requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`, though. Settings that *override* stuff in default filetype plugins should go into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim` instead.

Comment: Perfect. I forgot about the 'if fail' `||` redirect. (added link for ref in your answer) I'd love to dive into doing it properly as you suggest but I have to hack it "for now" because there's no spare time. Great additional feedback as well. I *had* these in the ahk.vim but they weren't being picked up in gvim; that's solved but I forgot to move them back. I'll do that now.